# How to get a Query object from solr query string

Tags: solr, lucene

There are solr query strings available from the log ,and the intent is to analyze the query to find out number fqs ,terms etc. Is there any api/parser available in solr/lucene to parse the entire query string and get the terms used ,filters used ,languages used ,fields used etc. Looked at QueryParser provided by lucene ,but it doesn't seem to help.

Example simple query string:

```
q=*:*&facet.field=Language&facet=true&f.Language.facet.limit=101&rows=0&sort=score desc,DefaultRelevance desc&fl=xxNonexx&bmf=50&wt=xml
```

Comment: Not in SOLRJ that I know of, you'll need to build the query yourself by pieces using the API :(

Answer (score 1):

You can use the SolrRequestParsers.parseQueryString() method to convert the string into Solr Params.  [Here's a link to documentation for it.](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/6_6_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/servlet/SolrRequestParsers.html#parseQueryString-java.lang.String-)
Below is an example.

```
String queryString = "q=*:*&facet.field=Language&facet=true&f.Language.facet.limit=101&rows=0&sort=score desc,DefaultRelevance desc&fl=xxNonexx&bmf=50&wt=xml";
MultiMapSolrParams solrParams = SolrRequestParsers.parseQueryString(String);
```

The code resides in the solr-core library, so you may need to add it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're not really looking for a parser but for a way to debug your query. Fortunately Solr has a debug parameter that you can use for such purpose as explained [here](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#Debugging). For instance you can add to your query:

```
q=*:*&facet.field=Language&facet=true&f.Language.facet.limit=101&rows=0&sort=score desc,DefaultRelevance desc&fl=xxNonexx&bmf=50&debug=true&wt=xml
```

Comment: These are quries from production logs and we want to analyze them. Not debug. Thanks